# Why Manikkavasagar isn't usually included in the Nayanars list?

Tags: shaivism, nayanar

Along with 63 Nayanars, why Manikkavasagar isn't included to make it as 64? He wrote one of the famous literature in Tamil i.e., Thiruvasagam. But he is included in the list of Nalvar(four people) along with Thirugnanasambandar, Thirunavukarasar, Sundharar. Why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

Nayanmar means servant of lord shiva. Now manickavasagar is kept as equal to the lord shiva  so he could not be as servant(nayanmat) that's it.

Comment: Hi, A very warm Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/17833). Further, kindly have a look at the [HSE HELP CENTER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help), and then get started in here properly. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: No one can be termed equal to Lord Shiva.I repeat no1.Period."[Manikkavasakar](http://thiruvenkidapuram.blogspot.com/2016/02/manickavasagar.html?m=1) is said to have born in Vadhavoor(Thiruvadhavoor, near by Melur in Madurai district),seven miles from Madurai on the banks of river Vaigai.He belonged to saivite temple priest guild. **His father was a temple priest.The group wore a top tilted knot to denote servitorship to Lord Siva like sambandar, etc.A mural and statuette of Manikkavasagar with head knot is seen in Tirupperunturai near Pudukkottai.**"So, he accepted serventship of Lord Shiva.

Comment: This advira philosophy is later invention